# Checking XML segments based on two conditions for the same node using Xpath and return true

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML -

```
<OrderData>
   <paylod>
      <Orders>
           <OrderStatus>Unshipped</OrderStatus>
            <NumberOfItemsShipped>1</NumberOfItemsShipped>
            <OrderType>StandardOrder</OrderType>
            <SellerID>POST to DB</SellerID>
      </Orders>
<Orders>
           <OrderStatus>Unshipped</OrderStatus>
            <NumberOfItemsShipped>1</NumberOfItemsShipped>
            <OrderType>StandardOrder</OrderType>
            <SellerID>POST to DB</SellerID>
      </Orders>
<Orders>
           <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>
            <NumberOfItemsShipped>1</NumberOfItemsShipped>
            <OrderType>StandardOrder</OrderType>
            
      </Orders>
<Orders>
           <OrderStatus>Unshipped</OrderStatus>
            <NumberOfItemsShipped>1</NumberOfItemsShipped>
            <OrderType>StandardOrder</OrderType>
            
      </Orders>
 </paylod>
</OrderData>
```

I need to check using Xpath if there is at least One Orders node with

```
<OrderStatus>Unshipped</OrderStatus>
```

and no

```
<SellerID>
```

tag for the same segment and return true.
I have used something like follwoing -

```
//Orders/OrderStatus[text()= "Shipped"] and .//Orders/SellerOrderId[text()= "POST to DB"]
```

But it is not working in all cases.
Request you to please add your input and help.

Thanks
Sugata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `//Orders[OrderStatus = 'Shipped' and not(SellerID)]` to select any such element or `boolean(//Orders[OrderStatus = 'Shipped' and not(SellerID)])` if you want a boolean value whether such a node exists.

Comment: Thank you Martin, this is working but returning the node as text, can we have expression that will return true or false/

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin Honnen for your quick help, perfectly worked.